# Select is not binding to a value when return from a state

Tags: angularjs, select, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have following select list in `ControllerA`

```
<select ng-model="selecteditem" ng-change="selectedItem(selecteditem)" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items" ></select>
```

and I have two methods, `Add()` and `Update()` in `ControllerB` and they are almost same

```
 $scope.add = function (g) {
    if (g != '') {
        .
        .
        .
        .
        $scope.grade = {};
        $state.go('grades', { selecteditem: g, items: $scope.items }, false);
    }
}
```

in `ControllerA`

```
 $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function (viewData) {
        if ($stateParams.items != null && $stateParams.items.length > 0) {
            $scope.items = $stateParams.items;
            $scope.selecteditem= $stateParams.selecteditem;
            ....
        }
        else {
           ......
        }
    });
```

in the `Add()` function, everything is working fine but in the `Update()` function, when I go back to `ControllerA`, select is not binding to `selecteditem` and displaying an empty value at start. What is the problem?

Comment: try to store  $scope.selecteditem in $rootScope.selecteditem and you will be able to access rootScope.selecteditem value in another Controller.
Because scope variable value is available within particular controller.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of options.
How are this controllers related?

1. You can always access parent's controller scope by $parent:

   `$scope.$parent.selectedItem = .....`
2. You can use $rootScope which is accessible from every controller

   `$rootScope.selectedItem = .....`

   you need to inject $rootScope into your controller
3. Using service is probably the best option:

   `.service('myService', function () {
       this.selectedItem = null;
   });`

You can inject your service into controllers and then set/access required variables like:

`myService.selectedItem = ..........`